# Synchronize Ajax Calls and executeQueryAsync SharePoint JS CSOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, csom

I have a problem synchronizing calls using Rest Api and JavaScript Object Model.

I'm currently working with Client Side Rendering to customize a view for a Document Library and add some functionalities in this custom UI.

I have a small collection of id's, and I'm looping through this collection and make some ajax calls with each of this items.

The results of this operation is to perform some tasks and to update my UI when all these operations are completed to refresh my UI and display some icons.

What I expect is to have 3 icons displayed only for my three first items.

The problem is that sometimes it displays all the icons, sometimes the two first... randomly.

I know that there is some problems with the synchronization of my executeQueryAsync calls, I've learned about jQuery Deferred object, I've tried to use them but without results.

Below you'll find screenshots of what I expect.

Expected :

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2C3CC814469DA54!3070&authkey=!AEf_C0XGDwfuFRY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

What would be the good way of using deferred ? Could anyone help ?

Thanks a lot

Elhmido

This is my main function for overriding the display :

```
(function () {

var accordionContext = {};
accordionContext.Templates = {};

// Be careful when add the header for the template, because it's will break the default list view render 
accordionContext.Templates.Item = itemTemplate;

// Add OnPostRender event handler to add accordion click events and style 
accordionContext.OnPreRender = [];
accordionContext.OnPreRender.push(function () {
    $(function () {
        IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("TEST Owners");
        **$.when(IsUserApprover(arrayOfIDS).done(function () {
            displayIcons();
        }));**
    });
});
accordionContext.OnPostRender = [];
accordionContext.OnPostRender.push(function () {
    $(function () {
        accordionOnPostRender();
        fixColumns();
        audit.relativeUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    });
});

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(accordionContext);
})();
```

**The function where I have the problem,**

```
function IsUserApprover(auditTab) {

var dfd = $.Deferred();

audit.tabIcons = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < auditTab.length; i++) {

    var uri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Audit')/items?$select=UserID&$filter=ID eq " + auditTab[i] + "";
    var call = $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    call.done(function (data, status, jqxhr) {

        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {

            var userId = data.d.results[0].UserID;
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

            var auditor = context.get_web().ensureUser(userId);
            context.load(auditor);

            //I think the problem is here because I don't know how to handle this call
            context.executeQueryAsync(userLoaded, userFailed);

            function userLoaded() {
                var auditorId = auditor.get_id();
                checkAuditorValidator(auditorId);
                dfd.resolve();
            }

            function userFailed(sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

            }
        });


    });

    call.fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        dfd.reject();
    });

}

return dfd.promise();
}



function checkAuditorValidator(auditorId) {


var uri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('SecurityMgmt')/items?" +
           "$select=Auditeur/ID,Validateur/ID" +
           "&$expand=Auditeur/ID,Validateur/ID" +
           "&$filter=(Auditeur/ID eq '" + auditorId + "') and (Validateur/ID eq '" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "')";

var call = $.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    async: false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
});

call.done(function (data, status, jqxhr) {

    if (data.d.results.length > 0) {

        if (audit.UserAdmin) {

            audit.tabIcons.push(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        audit.tabIcons.push(false);
    } 
});

call.fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error))

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

You should avoid synchronous ajax calls...

I had the same problem and solved by adding an id during the custom rendering of the fields (items), on the postrender call my service asynchronously and according the result edit the `OnPreRender` page using the previously added ids.

I also did some hacks...e.g overriding the standard function `RenderItemTemplate`. Yes I know, it's not very clean but it works like a charm.